# Making a API call in Vue component updating an object and passing it as prop always comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a Vue component I'm trying to update my products object with a new key:value pair and then continue passing it down to another component, but it always comes back as undefined. I am able to log out the updated object with the new key and value.

From what I can tell, the function needs to finish before being passed down, but I haven't been able to figure how to make that happen.. I've tried putting it in `onBeforeMount` lifecycle method, but that didn't work.

```
<template>
  <article>
    <div
      class="pi__wrapper"
      @mouseenter="toggleProductItemHovered()"
      @mouseleave="toggleProductItemHovered()"
    >
      <CollectionGridItemImages
        :product="activeProduct"
        :ss-product-id="product.id"
        :grid-view="gridView"
        :featured="featured"
      />
      <CollectionGridItemSwatches
        :product="updatedProducts"
        :active-product="activeProduct"
        :set-active-product="setActiveProduct"
        :set-is-loading="setIsLoading"
      />
    </div>
  </article>
</template>

<script>
import {
  ref,
  toRefs,
} from 'vue';

import CollectionGridItemImages from './collection-grid-item-images/CollectionGridItemImages';
import CollectionGridItemSwatches from './collection-grid-item-swatches/CollectionGridItemSwatches';

export default {
  name: 'CollectionGridItem',
  components: {
    CollectionGridItemImages,
    CollectionGridItemSwatches,

  },

  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    gridView: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    featured: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const {
      product,
    } = toRefs(props);

    const isLoading = ref(false);
    const productItemHovered = ref(false);

    const handle = _.handleize(product.value.tags.filter((str) => str.includes('Swatch:'))[0].split(':')[1]);

    const setIsLoading = (loading) => {
      isLoading.value = loading;
    };

    const toggleProductItemHovered = () => {
      productItemHovered.value = !productItemHovered.value;
    };

    let updatedProducts;

    const getSwatches = (url) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      _.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: `${url}?view=json`,
        success: (resp) => {
          onSuccess(resp);
          setIsLoading(false);
        },
        error: () => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        },
      });
    };

    const onSuccess = (resp) => {
      const updatedProduct = { ...product.value, swatches: resp.products };
      // this logs out what I want
      console.log(updatedProduct);
      updatedProducts = updatedProduct;
    };

    getSwatches(`/collections/all/swatch:${handle}`);
    // this is undefined
    console.log(updatedProducts, 'updated');
    return {
      productItemHovered,
      toggleProductItemHovered,
      updatedProducts,

    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I am always using the composition api with `<script setup>` so I am not sure, but shouldn't you return all properties you use in the template?

Comment: The problem is probably that you did not define updatedProducts as a `ref`: `const updatedProducts = ref(null);` and use it with `updatedProducts.value = ...`.

Comment: They're being returned at the end. All the other props work. So I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @Gabe Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't seem to work either.  It's not a const bc I'm reassigning the value from the onSuccess function

Comment: if it's not made with `ref` or `reactive` functions then the variable won't be [reactive](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html) and the child component won't receive the updated value.  const is always used with `ref` because the inner value can still be mutated regardless. Gabe's suggestion is 100% correct, though there may be other unseen errors/problems with the code.  It might be best to provide a github repo or sandbox that can reproduce the issue so others may help debug.